# How to get params of a POST endpoint with SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

The [SvelteKit documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-endpoints) gives an example for how to write GET endpoints with parameters...

```
export async function get({ params }) { /* [...] */ }
```

...and how to write POST endpoints without parameters...

```
export function post(request) { /* [...] */ }
```

How do I write POST endpoints with parameters? More precisely: What is the function signature that I have to use if I want to access both the parameters and the request body in my endpoint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do the same thing for `POST` request handling!

```js
export function post({ params, body }) { /* [...] */ }
```

All endpoint handlers are of type [`RequestHandler`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-endpoints), which are functions that take in a `ServerRequest` and have essentially the same function signature. `POST` requests also have the [`body` property](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-endpoints-body-parsing) on the request object, which is parsed according to the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: How do I actually get the body, or the formdata?? everything i try fails.   Even if I follow what it says in the error it fails...... THE ERROR:  To access the request body use the text/json/arrayBuffer/formData methods, e.g. `body = await request.json()`

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who might be stuck with the GET method.
The parameters for the GET request has changed.
**Params** has been replaced by **url**.

```
export async function GET({url}) {...}
```

The query parameters can then be extracted from the searchParams objects.

```
const text = url.searchParams.get('text');
```